# Вывод части значения поля PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, postgresql, select

Имеется таблица вида:

```
col1  |  col2  |    col3
------+--------+--------------
text11| text21 | 1234567890123
text21| text22 | 3210987654321
text31| text32 | 2342342554455
```

Необходимо сделать выборку из таблицы table, содержащую значения столбцов `col1` и `col2` полностью, а из значений `col3` брать только первые 10 цифр.

Проблема возникает именно с `col3`, не могу понять, как сделать выборку. Есть мысли использовать регулярные выражения. но не знаю, как к запросу прикрутить regexp `^\d{1,10}`

Comment: Используйте [substring()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: Подходит, но как вместо string использовать значение из таблицы? (substring(string from pattern)) Сейчас запрос выглядит так: SELECT col1,col2,substring('col3' from '^\d{1,10}') FROM TABLE;

Comment: `SELECT col1,col2,substring(col3 from '^\d{1,10}') FROM TABLE` ?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам:

```
SELECT col1,col2, substring(cast(col3 as text), 1 , 10)
FROM table;
```